# Multiple records not repeated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called TABLE_SCREW where I want to get the latest records for each code.
For example, in the table below you should obtain the records with ids 3 and 7.
I am a newbie in sql and I hope you can help me.

[image: TABLE_SCREW]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM TABLE_SCREW
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY Date DESC);
```

Another approach(may have better performance):

```
SELECT *  -- here * should be replaced with actual column names
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM TABLE_SCREW) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Though my preferred approach (no extra field), it is a hair less performant than where RN-=1   (+1)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Ok, I will post full version too :) Maybe one day we will get `SELECT * EXCEPT rn FROM ...`